# Why isn't my /execute command working?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I put in this command through Bedrock:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ sand 1 effect @p instant_damage 1 15
```

Although when I go to use it, it says:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected "remove": at "t ~ ~-1 ~ >>remove<< @p'

Please help, thanks.

Comment: you put ~~-1~ which is 4 coordinates. you only want 3 (x,y,z), so you would want too put ~~~

Comment: No, iirc ~-1 is “current position -1” although it might be -1~

Comment: I tried, it isn't working. It is bedrock, and its the McEdu bedrock so that might be it, but in some of the maps I've downloaded that command is used. It doesn't make sense.